# TFS 2013 (or Team Foundation Service) with Git hosted in Bitbucket

Tags: git, tfs, bitbucket

I am wanting to use Git and TFS, I will install TFS 2013. Wanted to know if you have how to create a TFS team project integrated with Git hosted on bitbucket?
I tried this with Team Foundation Service and could not, I could just create projects with Git hosted on https://XXXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/XXXX

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.

I am inferring from original post that you want to use TFS `ALM` features (work items, planning, build, testing) but use `Bitbucket` for source control, is that right?

I don't think you can do this, as `TFS` needs access to the source in order for all of the `ALM` features above to link in.

I think a solution might be to use the Git source control within TFS and then push it to bitbucket at certain times.

Comment: The problem is TFS is a destination not just another repo on your distributed source control network. This is quite sad and actually somewhat distorts the philosophy behind distributed source control. When you push to TFS, that is where you work and you cannot... wait, you can clone the tfs repo to bitbucket then from that point you can keep doing pull requests from bitbucket.

Answer (score 2):

Try [AppVeyor CI](http://www.appveyor.com). It's perfectly integrated with Git on BitBucket and GitHub.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this service.